# how to execute linux command via python loop

Tags: python, linux, shell

I have a list of files which will be used to extract by another linux script like this:

```
gzip -dc input/test_log.gz | bin/recreate state/object_mappings.sort > output/recreate.out
```

I need to change the name `test_log.gz` with my list of files with python loop, how can I execute this script dynamically. here is my code:

```
import os
from subprocess import call

files = os.listdir("/my directory/")
files.sort()
for i in files:
    call('gzip -dc input/test_log.gz | bin/recreate state/object_mappings.sort > output/recreate.out')
```

I dont know how to change this script with dynamic variable i??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `f-string` literal:

```
import os
from subprocess import call

files = os.listdir("/my directory/")
files.sort()
for file in files:
    call(f'gzip -dc {os.path.abspath(file)} | bin/recreate state/object_mappings.sort > output/recreate.out')
```

Comment: even file is in that directory

Comment: when i run this same command without python in shell, it works

Comment: I added absolute paths for files in script. Please, check you `files` list, maybe you need do define directory path correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the below method works.

```
from subprocess import call

files = ['input.txt', 'input1.txt', 'input2.txt', 'input3.txt']

for file in files:
    call(['sed', '-i', 's+NameToBeReplaced+NewName+', file])
```

- **sed** : is stream editor
- **-i** : Allows to edit the source file
- **+**: Is delimiter.
- **call**: Takes command in array format.

For example: if you want to run `ls -l input.txt`

```
call(['ls', '-l', file])
```

I hope the above information works for you .